# about "Question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I often run into problems where I am trying to decide which pattern to use in particular scenario, where to strike balance between good design and over-engineering, etc.

Those questions are almost guaranteed to solicit debate, extended discussion, etc...
So is Stack Overflow proper place for those questions? If not is Programmers a good venue? (I think they have similar guidelines).

**UPDATE**

Here is an example:
[Massive controller constructor argument list when using DI in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511811/massive-controller-constructor-argument-list-when-using-di-in-mvc)

I have few other questions like that I was thinking of asking, but I would not like to have them closed as unconstructive.

Comment: It would help if you could point us to a couple of example questions.

Comment: @Yannis: Sounds, good, just added one

Comment: Hm, the question you link to would be perfectly on topic on Programmers, but Stack Overflow also seems to welcome it (it's open, and upvoted). The same goes for your other question about breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: If diametrically opposed answers to a question are equally valid, it probably won't fit SO. On the other hand, if you're looking for the advantages and disadvantages of a technique/approach (that lie within the realm of objective fact), there isn't anything wrong with that. For example, asking what is wrong with using eval in JS is a perfectly OK question.

Comment: Ok thanks, that make sense - So focus more on advantages/disadvantages rather than opinions. I guess I will just try to frame those better. Looks weird to have an upvoted question, that has a number of close votes on it as well.

Comment: Related: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From (quickly) going through your profile, I think you'll enjoy Programmers, almost every one of your upvoted questions would be on topic there. The site is (a bit) more welcoming to subjective questions, and topics like software design and architecture are perfectly on topic. From the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on *conceptual questions about software development*. If you have a question about...
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing

If your question is about any of the above topics *and* it's build around an actual problem you are facing, feel free to ask it on Programmers. Make sure you read the rest of the FAQ, right under the list I've quoted above there's another list that's equally important.

Just keep in mind that "subjective" doesn't mean *anything goes*. While Programmers isn't as strict as Stack Overflow, if the motivation behind your question is (just) to gather opinions and/or start a discussion and/or start a flame war, we'll close it as well.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, from the FAQ it seems like that would be place to go.